# React Native Image doesn't rotate inside Animated.View on Android

Tags: android, react-native

So I have an Animated.View and inside it I have a View that has an Image inside it, I am rotating and translating the Animated.View when it is dragged through PanResponder. It works perfectly on ios emulator, the image inside the Animated.View rotates with it, however when I ran it on Android emulator, the Image inside the Animated.View doesn't rotate with it, it only changes position / translates. Is there something else that needs to be done for it to rotate on android?

```
this.rotate = props.position.x.interpolate({
     inputRange: [-screenWidth / 2, 0, screenWidth / 2],
     outputRange: ['-10deg', '0deg', '10deg'],
     extrapolate: 'clamp'
})
this.rotateandTranslate = {
    transform: [{
             rotate: this.rotate
         },
         ...props.position.getTranslateTransform()
     ]
}

<Animated.View style={this.rotateandTranslate}>
    <View> //this doesn't rotate on android, but it does on iOs
       <Image/>
    </View
</Animated.View
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#bear-in-mind `ensure the transform style perspective is in place. At this time some animations may not render on Android without it` this should help

Comment: Did you also try it on the image it self?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing. So... I plugged in my phone, set it to developer mode, and ran it on my personal phone. And it worked fine. The emulator sometimes doesn't show the animation, maybe because of available ram at the time. Not sure why, but it was actually working fine. Try it, maybe it'll work for you as well.

Comment: I tested it on an android 6 phone and it work fine, it doesn't work for android 7 and 8, is there anything that needs to be done?